# Swift: Get subclass variable after init in switch

Tags: swift, class, enums

I can't think of a good title for this.

If I have a switch statement in which I initialize a subclass from a class, then it won't let me use any functions or variables of the subclass. This is what I mean:

```
class Animal {}

class Cat: Animal {}

class Dog: Animal {
  func bark() {
    print("SWIFT DOES NOT LET ME BARK")
  }
}

enum AnimalType {
  case cat, dog
}

func getAnimal(type: AnimalType) -> Animal {
  let animal: Animal
  switch type {
  case .cat:
    animal = Cat()
  case .dog:
    animal = Dog()
    animal.bark() // Value of type 'Animal' has no member 'bark'
  }
  return animal
}
```

Please send help, I've been trying to think of a solution for too long.

Comment: What do you mean with: this doesn't work. Is there an error? If so please post the error.

Comment: @J.Paravicini Value of type 'Animal' has no member 'bark'... even though it's clear that it was initialized as a dog.

Comment: The problem is that ou declared the animal value variable with type "Animal" and even if you assign it a "Dog" variable it is still of type animal. You could downcast it to the roght variable

Comment: I don't really see the use of having the `animal` local variable here – just initialise and return the instances in their respective `case` bodies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instead of initializing `animal` with type `Dog` or `Cat` just upcast  using `as?` operator

Modify the function like

```
func getAnimal(type: AnimalType) -> Animal {
    var animal = Animal()
    switch type {
    case .cat:
        let cat = animal as? Cat
    case .dog:
        let dog = animal as? Dog
        dog?.bark()
        // Value of type 'Animal' has no member 'bark'
    }
    return animal
}
```

Comment: Those casts will never succeed because an `Animal` instance is not a `Dog` or a `Cat`.

Comment: In switch its checking against AnimalType and not Animal.

Comment: Try running it – the dog will never bark.

Answer (score 1):

Because the definition of function 'bark' is only inside 'Dog' class and you are trying to call it on 'Animal'.
One option would be to make an interface and implement it by 'Animal'
or following is the other option casting the object to 'Dog'.

```
 (animal as! Dog).bark() // Value of type 'Animal' has no member 'bark'
```

Answer (score 0):

A function returning an `Animal` can also return any `Animal` subclass.

```
func getAnimal(type: AnimalType) -> Animal {
    switch type {
    case .cat:
        return Cat()
    case .dog:
        let dog = Dog()
        dog.bark()
        return dog
    }
}
```

But to use the object outside the function you'll have to cast it with (for example) `as! Dog`:

```
let dog = getAnimal(type: .dog) as! Dog
dog.bark()
```